# Can a Quick Toss also be a Trip Attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, fighter, combat-maneuver

The Battle Master has two maneuvers that appear to work synergistically. Supposing a player has two superiority dice, may they perform both the the Quick Toss maneuver (TCoE) and Trip Attack (PHB)?

Performing this complex attack, would they be able to add two superiority dice to the damage of the thrown weapon?

> **Trip Attack**. When you hit a creature with a weapon attack, you can
> expend one superiority die to attempt to knock the target down. You
> add the superiority die to the attack's damage roll, and if the target
> is Large or smaller, it must make a Strength saving throw. On a failed
> save, you knock the target prone.